# Putting a 2D char array into a struct, don't know where to start

Tags: c, struct, multidimensional-array, strtok, atoi

i'm pretty new to forums so i hope i don't mess up.
I have a program that reads from a file, so far it puts the file into a 2D char array. I now need to strtok the 2D 'string' and place each part into a struct

here is the code

```
struct processes                 
{ 
    char processNumber[20]; 
    int quanta; 
    int priority; 
}process;
```

and

```
   int readSave(int argc, char ** argv)
{
int i,j,k,count;
size_t blocksize = 16;
char originalFile[256], newFile[1000][20];
int fileDes;
ssize_t status;
unsigned char buffer[blocksize];


strcpy(originalFile, argv[1]);

fileDes = open(originalFile, O_RDONLY); // open for reading

i=0;
status = 99;
while(status > 0 )  // while no error
{
    status = read(fileDes, buffer, blocksize);
    strcpy(newFile[i],buffer); //line 71

    for(k = 0; k <= blocksize; k++)
    {
        buffer[k] = 0;
    }
    i++;

    if(status < 0)
    {
        printf("\nERROR\n");
        exit(6);
    }   
}

//remove later
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) // prints out string to make sure it was input properly
{
    printf("%s", newFile[j]);
}

printf("\n");
close(fileDes);

//Don't know how to carry on

}
```

I hope you can help because i'm lost
EDIT
       struct processStruct processes[7000];
        while(newFile != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(processes[count].processNumber, strtok(newFile[count], " \n"));
        processes[count].quanta = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
        processes[count].priority = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));

```
    count ++;
}
```

i changed the struct and input given by @Igor but when i run it, i get a segmentation fault and when i compile with -Wall i get
    readtostring.c: In function ‘readSave’:
    readtostring.c:71:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ differ  in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
    /usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1:

Seems like you should do `strtok(newFile[something], " \n")` and not `strtok(newFile, " \n")`.
And don't forget to do `something++` in each iteration.

---

Issue 2:

You can't `strcpy` to `int`. Try instead:

```
process[something].quanta = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
process[something].priority = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
```

---

Issue 3:

`process` is a struct and not array of structs, so you can't do `process[something]`. Did you mean to create an array of structs: `processes process[20];`

Comment: I compiled the code with the changes 
    struct processStruct processes[7000];
 while(newFile != NULL)
 {
  strcpy(processes[count].processNumber, strtok(newFile[count], " \n"));
  processes[count].quanta = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
  processes[count].priority = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
  
  count ++;
 }

Comment: i think my problem is when i try to read the file to string, i have to use read() not fread() or anything else, and if i put it in a single string it should work better than a 2d array but i don't know how